# Query custom metric with namespace on application insights Log with KQL

Tags: azure-application-insights

Is it possible to query app insights custom metrics and include the namespace in the result?

The Metrics Explorer provides a dropdown for namespace, but querying the customMetric table in the Log view doesn't seem to provide a column or other way of getting the namespace?

To clarify I am writing metrics to an app insights resource using

```
TelemetryClient.GetMetric(new MetricIdentifier("namespace","id","dimension")).TrackValue(1,"count");
```

In the portal, I select the app insights resource, the Monitoring "Blade"? then Metrics. This gives me a drop down selection of namespace with my name spaces listed.

If I select Monitoring, Logs instead I can write KQL against customMetrics table ie

```
customMetrics | summarize count() by name
```

What I want to do is (for example)

```
customMetrics | summarize count() by namespace
```

Obviously the actual query is more complex, I don't need a way of running that particular query but of accessing the namespace in the same KQL query as the other customMetrics data

Answer (score 1):

Currently namespace is not available as a column under `customMetrics` in Application Insights Logs. [Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/essentials/metrics-custom-overview?toc=%2Fazure%2Fazure-monitor%2Ftoc.json#namespace) are just used as a way to organize metrics so that you can easily find them in Azure Monitor metrics explorer.

The namespace is sent and stored in Azure Monitor as part of Metric Definition object, but unfortunately metric definitions are not exposed in Application Insights Logs. If you are interested in getting the namespace directly from metric definition, then consider using REST API which returns all metric definition fields including namespace ([API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metric-definitions/list#metricdefinition)).

However, if you want to work with custom metrics as a log table and have a field for grouping metrics, filtering them or displaying this field in the results, I suggest sending it as custom dimension.

Here is an example of how custom dimensions can be tracked along metric values. I called the dimension `metricCategory` in this example just to avoid confusion with the standard namespace field:

```
MetricIdentifier id = new MetricIdentifier("metricNamespace","metricId", "metricCategory");
Metric computersSold  = _telemetryClient.GetMetric(id);
computersSold.TrackValue(1,"Namespace/category name");
```

Then this category can be used in KQL queries as any other custom metric field:

```
customMetrics | summarize count() by tostring(customDimensions.metricCategory)
```

Comment: although you are right about the col not being available, it doesn't explain how the metrics tab is able to have its drop down and why the namespace is sent with every metric. Clearly the information is sent and stored on app insights. I am looking for a way to access it rather than a work around.

Comment: Yes, the namespace is sent and stored in Azure Monitor as part of Metric Definition object, but unfortunately metric definitions are not exposed in Application Insights Logs and there is no ideal solution here. If you are interested in getting the namespace directly from metric definition, then consider using REST API which returns all metric definition fields including namespace https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/metric-definitions/list#metricdefinition. However, if you need it in Application Insights Logs queries, the workaround with custom dimensions can be a better approach.

Comment: is there a way to query by metric definition id or something? clearly the metrics tab does exactly this under the hood

Comment: Only via REST API or Azure Powershell cmdlets from what I know :(

Answer (score 0):

You can get Filter out the namespace in an **InsightsMetrics.** which follows

[image]

#### These are the namespaces in our Log Analytics workspace

[image]

If you want to add the **custom metrics** with **namespace** you have to add the **custom metrics** with the specific **namespace** to retrieve both ***metrics*** and ***namespaces***.

Please check the [blog](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/monitor-query/v/1.0.0#handle-metrics-query-response) to add custom metrics and namespace in application insights and retrieve those accordingly.

Refer [here](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-kusto-query-language-to-solve-a-data-problem/) for more information

Comment: hmm ok, I guess the difference here is I am querying customMetrics on an application insights resource, and you are querying a log analytics workspace resource.

Comment: is there a way to bring the app insights data into Log Analytics without restricting the namespace field?